# How to solve this R package tidyverse error

Tags: r

Good afternoon!

Under R i get this error while trying to load `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
     namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.7 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
```

Session info :

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] intervals_0.15.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.0   R6_2.5.0         rsconnect_0.8.16 generics_0.1.0   tools_4.0.0      glue_1.4.0      
 [7] tinytex_0.25     vctrs_0.3.2      xfun_0.13        rlang_0.4.7
```

Error while trying to update `rlang` (solved ):

```
remotes::install_github("r-lib/rlang")
Downloading GitHub repo r-lib/rlang@HEAD
Running `R CMD build`...
* checking for file 'C:\Users\Mouad\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgjncCL\remotes29b8390c1ebf\r-lib-rlang-98515e9/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'rlang':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to process help pages
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'rlang_0.4.10.9000.tar.gz'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
Error in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) : 
  (converted from warning) problem copying C:\Users\Mouad\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\Mouad\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
* removing 'C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
Error in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) : 
  (converted from warning) problem copying C:\Users\Mouad\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\Mouad\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'rlang' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Mouad/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgjncCL/file29b84c897087/rlang_0.4.10.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Loading of `tidyverse` !

```
library('tidyverse')
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Mouad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.3
```

Thank you a lot for help!

Comment: Update `rlang` to at least v0.4.10.

Comment: package ‘rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: It seems that you might be using quite an old version of R, adding the output from `sessionInfo()` to your post would help identify what version issues are happening.

Comment: @Miff , I updated the post with the required session info !

Comment: rlang is available for that version of R.  I would suggest trying again and/or changing the mirror you're using.

Comment: @Dason , it fails to update rlang ! ( post updated )

Comment: "ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?" This suggests to me you have multiple instances of R running, and at least one of them has rlang loaded. I suggest closing everything, reopen Rstudio and try to update rlang again.

Comment: @TouMou It's available via CRAN - I would suggest trying that route before installing through github.  Also you should load a vanilla session of R before trying to install.

Comment: @Dason , the rlang issue is now solved ! However , I have another problem ! ( see post !)

Comment: +1 to @Phil's comment about restarting R. When R is using a package that has compiled code (i.e., an `.so` or `.dll` compiled shared object), it latches on to the DLL and doesn't allow it to be removed/deleted while open. I've had limited success using `detach("package:nameofpkg", unload=TRUE, force=TRUE)`, but not enough to make it a perfect recommendation. Ultimately, whenever I get `ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?`, I close R, reopen it fresh (no `.Rdata` files) and re-attempt the installation. (Rarely I've had to clean up `RLIB/00LOCK*` directories.)

Comment: I don't know how to describe this situation but it seems like many namespaces need to be updated in my R version . ( I already tried to migrate an older R installation from windows 7 to the windows 10 that I'm using now )

Comment: Thank you anyway for your valuable help!

Comment: The problem is completely solved ! The question could be closed !